# A way for a program to constantly run

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing a website that will  be using an SQL database. However I am needing the database to be updated with real-time information. I have no problems doing this as I have written a C# program to do this. However as I want this data to be updated 24/7. It's not appropriate to run it on my own machine. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Run it as a service on the server or run it as a SQL Job.

Comment: Get a small virtual machine in Amazon Cloud and run your process there. You will have to move your DB there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options:

**If you have a dedicated server:**

- Create your application as a console application and put it in startup
- Create your application as a console application and using Windows Task Scheduling run it with your required frequency.
- Create it as a windows service that will always run

**If you don't have a dedicated server:**

- Use libraries like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to perform task scheduling in your web application

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by saying SQL you mean Microsoft SQL Server...

As already told the optimal solution is to code a Windows service. In case you are working with express edition of visual studio this can be tricky without the related template which is available only on paid edition or  with 2017 community , so a possibility is to make an executable program and activate it using task scheduler and the repeat every option.
To be honest I would prefer to keep everything inside SQL , using SQL server agent you can execute jobs defined among SSIS , basically a rebranded and extended DTS which can easily operate on DB, have a better logging than the primitive OS task scheduler. No need to go on was or cloud, it is just a SQL server function that need to be enabled by the DBA, if not already used.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't available in community? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977280/windows-service-template-for-visual-studio-2017)