# Windows Service Template for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

The Windows Service Template no longer displays by-default for new projects in Visual Studio 2017....and the installer has no 'search' capability.

All this AZURE stuff is great, but I still gotta do normal 'on-prem' work too...and I hate maintaining 2 versions of Visual Studio.

Any thoughts here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just checked here. I see project "Windows Service (.NET Framework)" under the Windows Classic Desktop folder under Visual C#.

(Visual Basic has a similar entry.)

Only some templates are shown in parent folders, for more specialist templates you need to be more specific.

But also the search finds both.

NB I selected ".NET Desktop" workload on install, which I see you have not.

Comment: Ah!  Okay...that install said WPF (and I didnt notice Console).  I wouldn't think to bundle Windows Services into it too.  Thanks

Comment: Okay...that did it.  Thanks

Comment: In VS 2017 Pro Windows Service does not appear anywhere.  What am I missing?

Comment: @PrescottChartier Have you installed the .NET Desktop workload in the installer? If you have and Windows Service is still not present then please ask a new question.

Comment: I had not, installed it and I was able to create the project.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Check the .NET desktop development option in the installer, then click Modify.

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Installer]

Comment: Yep! That was it for me. I usually stick to Web Development, but in this case I needed to do some Desktop Development stuff as well. ;)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

VS2017 --> New project --> Visual Basic or Visual C# --> Windows Classic Desktop --> Windows Service

Answer (score 6):

Also check out this recent post (currently dated 2017-3-30) from MS to do it without the project template:

[How to: Write Services Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-write-services-programmatically)

The key points are as follows:

- Create a new project
- Add "System.dll" and "System.ServiceProcess.dll" as References
- Create a class inheriting from ServiceBase and create a Program.cs with Main exactly like the template project does

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking Windows Template Studio Universal then You have to install the extension in Visual Studio.

Go to Tools menu >> Extensions & Updates >> Online >>then search for Windows Template Studio

OR go to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio#overview

[image]